# Selenium Test Case not getting executed with Jest

Tags: node.js, selenium, jestjs

I am working on setting up an automation test suite for an application using selenium and jest and it turns out that the console never reaches the inner body of the minimalist test case written below.

```
describe('When a user Opens Launchpad', () => {

test('It should be able to Navigate to Tasks Application without errors', async () => {
  driver.get('http://localhost:4004/fiori.html').then(function () {
  const temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("li[@id='__tile11']"));
  temp.then(function (element){
    element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
    expect(element.getText()).toBe("VT Dashboard");
  })
});
}, 200000);
```

});

I looked online and tried multiple fixes like putting the driver.get() method above all these functions, making the test cases synchronous and using getText() instead of getAttribute() but none of them worked.

I either get an element not found error (The element actually exists when I check it on the chromium browser) or the test case executes successfully without reaching the expect statement in debug mode.

Bottomline is that driver.findElement() returns a promise instead of an element and would be great if I could get an element instead of promise.

Any help or correction here would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Console of Test Case Executed Successfully]

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

If the function is async you should return the promise chain from that function or just use `await` keyword. So try following:

```js
test('It should be able to Navigate to Tasks Application without errors', async () => {
  await driver.get('http://localhost:4004/fiori.html');
  const temp = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("li[@id='__tile11']"));

  element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
  expect(element.getText()).toBe("VT Dashboard");
}, 200000);
```

or

```
test('It should be able to Navigate to Tasks Application without errors', async () => {
  return driver.get('http://localhost:4004/fiori.html').then(function () {
    const temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("li[@id='__tile11']"));
    temp.then(function (element){
      element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
      expect(element.getText()).toBe("VT Dashboard");
    })
  });
}, 200000);
```